# Decode base64 in array to figure out hackers intents

Tags: php, base64, decode

A WordPress site of a client was recently hacked due to a theme vulnerability and I am now in the process of cleaning up and fortifying. I found guncompress(base64_decoded code. When I decoded it I had more base64 in an array:

```
$GLOBALS['_1780441916_']=Array(base64_decode('' .'ZXJ' .'yb3Jfc' .'mVwb3J' .'0a' .'W5'.'n'),base64_decode('Y3VybF9pb' .'ml0'),base64_decode('c
```

How can I decode base64 in an array on my localhost?

Comment: The same way you already did. Just decode each element in turn.

Comment: I used a print_r to show the array. That way I was able to check it. No I will work on decoding the rest. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try to using evalhook.so.
You need:

- PHP >= 5.2
- php5-devel
- PHP Zend Optimizer

download source from http://php-security.org/downloads/evalhook-0.1.tar.gz

then unpack and install it

```
tar xvfz evalhook-0.1.tar.gz
cd evalhook
phpize 
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and you can use it from console.

```
php -d extension=evalhook.so encoded_script.php
```

where encoded_script.php is your encoded script.
every time it ask you

```
Do you want to allow execution? [y/N]
```

Type Y if your code after execution have some "base64_decode" in it.
Then when you get something like that

```
$GLOBALS['_889997777_'] = Array(
```

...

```
$GLOBALS['_224568216_'][21]('Xr' . 'x8f7g=')
);
```

Just run after that `var_export($GLOBALS['_889997777_']);die;` and you get all functions name, than you can replace it. Here is link that can automate it http://pastebin.com/kBj4iqWh